# Редирект http-https c node js express, headers.host = 127.0.0.1:port

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, https, express

Есть сервер:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res){
  res.render('index', data);
});

app.listen(8082);
```

он лежит на vpn и работает через проксирование, nginx занимается https.
Стандартные способы редиректа не работают:

```
app.all(function (req, res, next) {
   if (req.secure) {
       // request was via https, so do no special handling
       next();
    } else {
       // request was via http, so redirect to https
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});
```

Так как у меня req.headers.host выводит 127.0.0.1:8082. 
Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Вам надо, чтобы `nginx` перенаправлял запросы на порт 8082?

Comment: Нет, он уже так делает. Мне надо редирект с http на https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте редирект прям на  Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

так как nginx у вас сейчас стоит на listen 443 ssl вы также в нем добавляете слушатель на 80 порт для редиректа

nodejs app так и работает по 8082 порту (http)

схема работы выглядит примерно так

> client(443:https) **=>** [ server nginx (443:https) -> nodejs_app(8082:http) ]

redirect

> client(80:https) **=>**  server nginx (80:https) redirect return "https"; **=>** client(443:https) **=>** [ server nginx (443:https) -> nodejs_app(8082:http) ]

таким образом соединение между клиентом и сервером защищено а делать еще  ssl на передачи данных с  nginx на expresss не считаю нужным так как это один и тот-же хост а шифрование и дешифрование занимает  некоторое время

Ecли у вас не получится отправте  конфигурацию nginx я помогу

Comment: У меня доступа к nginx нет, а постоянно писать провайдеру, чтоб он делал мне редиректы не очень удобно. Раньше когда сайт был на пхп я редиректы писал в .htaccess может можно его сейчас как то прикрепить?

Comment: если у вас есть ssh доступ вы можете делать это сами для этого не нужно писать хостеру  хостер просто заходит и делает тоже что бы делали  вы у вас есть доступ по ssh ?

Comment: ssh есть сейчас поищу тогда как можно настраивать его и отпишусь

Comment: # cd /etc/nginx/  если есть эта папка то там несколько вариантов как могли с  конфигурировать sites-enabled или conf.d зависит от того как там сконфигурировал хостер  посомтрите в каком из фале есть proxy на ваш хост  просматривать файлы вы можете через nano [filename]

Comment: @medve_dev мой телеграм если что помогу